# Un-minify chrome's heapsnapshot

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, minify, heap-memory

Using **chrome dev tools**, I have taken a **heap snapshot** of my website. My website runs the **minified JS**.

I would like to be able to be able to analyze the snapshot for memory leaks but most of the code in there, as expected, is minified, making things harder to investigate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a minified js as I guess through your question.
You can make this js file to be understood for solving the problems you face.

To achieve this please follow these steps.

1. Go to - https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/
2. You will see three buttons HTML, CSS and JS.
3. Click on js button.
4. Copy and paste the whole js file into the text area (at the right-hand side which says line number
5. Click on the clean button.
6. On the right hand you will get the cleaned version of your minified file.
   You can use this approach to beautify the HTML and CSS files.

Comment: I actually have a heap snapshot which contains the minified code. I would like to inspect the un-minified version in the heap dump

Comment: In this case, I think you have to do this manually by checking and comparing these two files.